# Checking if variable is null in Gitlab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

How to check a null variable in Gitlab pipeline when it's declared with a content of another null variable? Like the variable `VAR_NULL` below when `NO_VAR` is null:

```yaml
variables:
  VAR_EMPTY: ""
  VAR_NULL: "${NO_VAR}"
```

Check the pipeline result out where only `VAR_EMPTY == ""` and `NO_VAR == null` evaluate to **true** all others are **false**.

**Pipeline result** (*a screenshot for convenience, the full result: https://gitlab.com/labaz/test-gitlab-pipeline-null-var/-/pipelines/493036820*):
[image: Pipeline result]

**Full pipeline script** (https://gitlab.com/labaz/test-gitlab-pipeline-null-var/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml):

```yaml
variables:
  VAR_EMPTY: ""
  VAR_NULL: "${NO_VAR}"

jobTest-Var_Empty-IsNull:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  rules:
    - if: '$VAR_EMPTY == null'
  script:
    - 'echo "VAR_EMPTY IS null"'

jobTest-Var_Empty-IsEmpty:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  rules:
    - if: '$VAR_EMPTY == ""'
  script:
    - 'echo "VAR_EMPTY IS \"\""'

jobTest-Var_Null-IsNull:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  rules:
    - if: '$VAR_NULL == null'
  script:
    - 'echo "VAR_NULL IS null"'

jobTest-Var_Null-IsEmpty:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  rules:
    - if: '$VAR_NULL == ""'
  script:
    - 'echo "VAR_NULL IS Empty"'

jobTest-No_Var-IsNull:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  rules:
    - if: '$NO_VAR == null'
  script:
    - 'echo "NO_VAR IS null"'

jobTest_No_Var-IsEmpty:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  rules:
    - if: '$NO_VAR == ""'
  script:
    - 'echo "NO_VAR IS Empty"'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is that `VAR_NULL: "${NO_VAR}"` is not a null variable. It's actually the same thing as `VAR_EMPTY: ""` -- you are declaring the variable (therefore it is not null) with an empty value.

The only way to test if the variable was created with another empty variable is to test the original variable itself. That is, test `NO_VAR`, not `VAR_NULL`.

An alternative strategy would be to use `rules:variables:` in order to conditionally declare `VAR_NULL`

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$NO_VAR' # or '$NO_VAR != null' depending on what you want
      variables:
        VAR_NULL: "$NO_VAR"
    - when: always

jobTest-Var_Null-IsNull:
  rules:
    - if: '$VAR_NULL == null'
  script:
    - echo "VAR_NULL is null"
```

Comment: Currently, we got a template pipeline script (`.gitlab-ci.yml`) and the projects may set up it mapping the internal variables with their external ones (project or group variables). Having to check an external variable (coupling) is what we would like to avoid, so in that case it sounds better to just fix the variable names internally (and consequentially the external ones). Thanks for the help, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as any "if" is matched the job runs.
there's no overriding it with a later "never"
also 'if when never' - who thought that was a good idea?

Anyhow to make the if less matchy ... you can use parentheses.

```yaml
      rules:
        - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $SOME_VAR == null)
```

However this doesn't work:

```yaml
       - if: ('$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == develop' && $SOME_VAR == null)
```

not sure why considering this is valid...

```yaml
       - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == develop'
```

essentially I want to skip some jobs when 'some_var' is set (which happens when I run a manual pipeline)

So putting it all together ...

And before your eyes glaze over "workflow" and its "rules" are a separate beast from "job_name:" "rules:"
ostensibly workflow needs "always or never" and the rules can control when jobs run.. but only if you put a "never" .. unless i'm missing something... )

```yaml
    workflow:
      rules:
        - if: '$SOMEVAR == null'
          variables:
            BLOCK_JOB: "False"
        - when: always
```

#then in my job we can do something like:

```yaml
    rules:
       - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop" && $BLOCK_JOB)
```

yes all of that because this doesn't work

```yaml
      - if: ('$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == develop' && $SOME_VAR == null)
```

so now I can have a job that runs on develop unless its run manually (which is when I set SOMEVAR)
and then its skipped.

Workflow also seems to just randomly refuse to do somethings...

for example this Doesn't work ( trying to set a var based on project name) never evals as true so CI_PATH_TYPE remains unset... but imo looking at it with my wetware... it should...

```yaml
    rules:
    - if: $CI_PROJECT_NAME == "some-project-name"
      variables:
        CI_PATH_TYPE: project
```

But this does? because.. null is magic..?

```yaml
    rules:
    - if: '$somevar == null'
      variables:
        BLOCK_JOB: "False"
```

also any time something is quoted in various ways in these examples gitlab ci made me do it exactly like that, any other variations and it shits the bed.

so once again the latest tool is just more black magic, hot take: gitlab-ci is bad.